# SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Problem:

SelectedIndexchanged does not fire. I tried investigating with a breakpoint but it does not even get to the event.
I made the event by double clicking on the combobox. But it did not help.
Please advice.

Here is the code:

```
    protected void nav_dd_parent_edit_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }   
    <td width="55%" class="style1" height="20px">
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="nav_dd_parent_edit" runat="server" 
                                        DataSourceID="sp_GetNavParents_Edit" DataTextField="Name" 
                                        DataValueField="NavItemId" Height="24px" ReadOnly="FALSE" Width="375px" 
                                        onselectedindexchanged="nav_dd_parent_edit_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </td>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                //Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = true;
                //SiteMaster.g_solution = "Couche-Tard - QV";
                //SiteMaster.g_solution_id = 27;
                nav_dd_parent.DataBind();
                if (SiteMaster.g_solution != null && SiteMaster.g_solution != "")
                {
                    nav_literal.Text = "Solution: " + SiteMaster.g_solution;
                    nav_hidden_SoltnId.Value = SiteMaster.g_solution_id.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    nav_literal.Text = "Please select a solution first from the 'Solution Template' Tab.";
                    panel_top.Visible = false;
                }
            }
```

Comment: post your Page_Load code

Answer (score 6):

You're not seeing your breakpoint get hit because the dropdownlist is not posting back when the selection changes.

Set `AutoPostBack` to `true` and you should be all set.

Comment: I tried that as well... but when I change the selected value to something else it automatically selects the default value.

Comment: Well one step at a time.  If you want the DDL to post back when you change the selected index, you *must* set `AutoPostBack`.  If after doing that you're having other problems, then that's a separate issue.

Comment: After setting AutopostBack to true, it just automatically selects the default value whenever I try to change the selected value.

Comment: Ahhh - I'll bet your databinding your DD after each postback in your page_load method.  Make sure you only bind it ONCE, on your first load.  `if (!Page.IsPostback) { bindYourDropDownList(); }`

Comment: @user1047883 Ok, well gather up the relevant code, including your DDL *with* AutoPostBack, and post a new question describing your new problem

Answer (score 1):

I noticed your DropDownList Id is "nav_dd_parent_edit", but your Page_Load is calling the Databind method on "nav_dd_parent" - could that be part of the problem?

Anyway, I did a simplified version of your DropDownList that works fine - perhaps it might help.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="55%" class="style1" height="20px">
            <asp:DropDownList  
                ID="nav_dd_parent" 
                runat="server" 
                DataTextField="Name" 
                DataValueField="NavItemId" 
                Height="24px" 
                ReadOnly="FALSE" 
                Width="375px" 
                onselectedindexchanged="nav_dd_parent_edit_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                AutoPostBack="true">
             </asp:DropDownList>
         </td>
    </tr>
</table>


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {                
        nav_dd_parent.Items.Add(new ListItem("Item 1", "1"));
        nav_dd_parent.Items.Add(new ListItem("Item 2", "2"));
        nav_dd_parent.Items.Add(new ListItem("Item 3", "3"));
    }
}

protected void nav_dd_parent_edit_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int codeGetsHere = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Few notes to keep in mind as below:

a. Set 'AutoPostBack' to true :

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="nav_dd_parent_edit" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true"
        DataSourceID="sp_GetNavParents_Edit" DataTextField="Name" 
        DataValueField="NavItemId"
        onselectedindexchanged="nav_dd_parent_edit_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

b. Always bind on not postback time :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        nav_dd_parent_edit.DataSource = yourDataSourceName;
        nav_dd_parent_edit.DataBind();
    }
}
```